# How do I include for loops and if statements in dictionary comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I'm learning how to use dictionaries currently and I sort of know how to do dictionary comprehension with for loops. However I want to include an if statement into the for loop. Something similar to this:

```
Dict = {}
for i in range(11):
    if i < 5:
        Dict[i] = 1
    else:
        Dict[i] = 0
```

How do I turn that mess into dictionary comprehension?

Comment: [Asking on Stack Overflow is not a substitute for doing your own research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/843953) This question has been answered many times on SO and covered in most decent tutorials on dict comprehensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dict = {i: 1 if i < 5 else 0 for i in range(11)}
```